# Inno setup "The drive or UNC share you selected does not exist or is not accessible", why?

Tags: inno-setup

I have written an application in Inno Setup to install files on users PCs. The application works well when I test it on XP in Parallels running on Mac. But when the user tries to install, in Xp and in 7, they get to the Wizard and start the install and then get the message:

> `Error. The drive or UNC share you selected does not exist or is not accessible`

I have now managed to get the log file that the program produces:

```
2012-11-11 14:09:21.992   Log opened. (Time zone: UTC+00:00)

2012-11-11 14:09:21.992   Setup version: Inno Setup version 5.5.2 (a)

2012-11-11 14:09:21.992   Original Setup EXE: C:\Users\Ali\Documents\rninstaller.exe

2012-11-11 14:09:21.992   Setup command line: /SL5="$9049C,86159698,54272,C:\Users\Ali\Documents\rninstaller.exe" /SPAWNWND=$D049A /NOTIFYWND=$140476 /log="rnlog"

2012-11-11 14:09:21.992   Windows version: 6.1.7601 SP1  (NT platform: Yes)

2012-11-11 14:09:21.992   64-bit Windows: Yes

2012-11-11 14:09:21.992   Processor architecture: x64

2012-11-11 14:09:21.992   User privileges: Administrative

2012-11-11 14:09:21.992   64-bit install mode: No

2012-11-11 14:09:21.992   Created temporary directory: C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Local\Temp\is-MQ2FF.tmp

2012-11-11 14:09:28.201   RestartManager found an application using one of our files: ?O?O?O?I?O?O?O?I?O?O?O?O?O?O?O?O?O?O?O?O?O?O?O?O?O?O?O?ODO?O?O?O?O?I?I?I?I?I?I?I?I?I?I?I?I?I?I?I?I?I?I?I?I?I?I?I?I?I?O?O?O?O?O?O?O?O?O?I?I?i

2012-11-11 14:09:28.201   RestartManager found an application using one of our files: 

2012-11-11 14:09:28.201   RestartManager found an application using one of our files: 

2012-11-11 14:09:28.201   RestartManager found an application using one of our files: 

2012-11-11 14:09:28.201   RestartManager found an application using one of our files: 

2012-11-11 14:09:28.201   Can use RestartManager to avoid reboot? No (262758)

2012-11-11 14:09:28.201   Message box (OK):
                          The drive or UNC share you selected does not exist or is not accessible. Please select another.

2012-11-11 14:09:31.592   User chose OK.

2012-11-11 14:09:31.592   Deinitializing Setup.

2012-11-11 14:09:31.592   Log closed.
```

I cannot see what is going on here. Can anyone help ?

Comment: You have to do some research and ask some questions to you, and include the relevant info in your question here. For example: It happens at a particular file? any file? is the destination selected by the user a UNC path? can she write to that path? what's the destination you have for that file in your script? do you execute any custom code in your installation phase? is there something special in the target machine? it happens on any machine or on a specific one/set? and so on...

Comment: I must admit that I am puzzled. I used the Inno Setup wizard to create the application. There is no Code section. The File section moves files into a new folder within My Documents on the user's PC. The user is not asked to make any decisions during the process. There is nothing special about the target machines that I am aware of. It is happening so far on two PCs - one running XP, one running 7. What puzzles me is the error message's reference to a drive or UNC share - in the application the files are directed to the users' My Documents folder ! Any thoughts ?

Comment: in Windows it is possible to configure the documents folder to a UNC path, are you asking for admin privileges in your installer?

Comment: Hi jachguate. Thanks for helping me with this. I don't think that I am asking for admin privileges in the installer. What I would really like to do is to get hold of the log file and see what is going on. I have Setuplogging=yes in [Setup]and in [Code] I copy the logfile to a new file in the {app} folder if CurStep = ssDone. But of course that will only copy on sucessful completion. I cannot find the file produced by Setuplogging. Do you know how I can get hold of that file ?

Comment: You can run the setup with the /LOG="filename" parameter to take control of where the file is created. Take a look at [Force log file](http://www.vincenzo.net/isxkb/index.php?title=Force_log_file_with_Inno_Setup_versions_before_5.2.0), but that's another question!

Comment: I have followed your advice and have used /LOG="filename" to get access to the logfile but I am no closer to seeing what is going wrong. Is it any clearer to you , jachguate ? I have put the content of the logfile into the original question. All the best !

Comment: AFAICS from the sources, the error is raised in 'ValidateCustomDirEdit' when Inno Setup is unable to validate the target drive. There should be something wrong with the destination folder at client site.

Comment: Thanks Sertac Akyuz. I have: DefaultDirName=\\psf\Home\Documents\Progname folder in [Setup] section      and Source: "\\psf\Home\Documents\Progname Folder\Progname.exe"; DestDir: "{userdocs}"; Flags: ignoreversion onlyifdoesntexist in [Files] section - I still cannot see where the bug is. Any thoughts with this additional information?

Comment: @John - There's no server named psf?

Comment: Hi Sertac Akyuz. No, there's no server named psf. This piece of code was set up by the wizard, to place the files in a folder within the Documents folder on the user's PC. I think that \\psf\ says that. But I am starting to doubt what I know here ! In fact my current speculation is that this is a problem caused by my using XP on a Mac running Parallels software. Many thanks for your input - do keep the ideas coming !

Comment: @John - You're welcome! If there's no such server and if the user don't change the default installation directory then it is expected that Inno Setup complains about the drive. If you want the files to end up in documents then set the default installation directory to {userdocs}\PrognameFolder\ .

Comment: @Sertac - That solved it. Thank you so much ! How do we complete this ? Do you need to put this in as a solution - I'd like you to get the acknowledgement. All the best

Comment: @John - You're welcome. I tried to formulate it as an answer. See if it's ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As resolved in the comments to the question, the setup script in the question had a hard coded `DefaultDirName` which consisted of a server name that didn't existed at the client site. This resulted in the *"The drive or UNC share you selected does not exist or is not accessible"* error. This is why [`DefaultDirName`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_defaultdirname), most often, *"is prefixed by a directory constant"*.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this error for a different reason. My script did not have any hard coded paths, UNC or otherwise. This is on a Windows 10 machine. I had installed the application on a flash drive, but later when trying to install another version to the PC, the flash drive was not present. The install was failing because Windows couldn't uninstall the previous version, and Inno setup was trying to update the installed version. To check this, open Control Panel and select Programs and Features. If a version of your application is already installed, attempt to uninstall it. If this fails, then your setup will give the same error documented by OP.

I hope this helps anyone else who runs into this issue.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone else who winds up in this post looking for an solution to the "driver or UNC share does not exist" problem", I found the problem to trace back to leftovers from the last install, in particular the Uninstall executable.

If you don't have the uninstall executable anymore, and Windows 10 "Add or Remove Programs" is unable to uninstall (probably due to the missing `uninst.exe`), you can try to do some registry hacking to make it install.

Go on `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\` and scan the entries for the one referencing the uninstall executable for your software. Zap it dead, the whole key. Then - try to install your program again.

There's another location for uninstall keys:

- `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\`
- `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`
- `Computer\HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`
- `Computer\HKEY_USERS\S....\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`

You may want to look up the entries in those places as well.