# innosetup : "the driver or unc share you selected does not exist or is not accessible. Please select another."

Tags: windows-8, inno-setup

Running an installation of inno setup on windows 8 , choosing a network drive (mapped driver), will result in an error message :

> "the driver or unc share you selected does not exist or is not
>   accessible. Please select another."

Googling led to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13218274/inno-setup-the-drive-or-unc-share-you-selected-does-not-exist-or-is-not-accessi), which suggested to change the

'DefaultDirName'

to be

```
DefaultDirName={sd}\folder
```

Yield no change.

Opening up the [inno setup got from git hub](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc) showed the the massage is held on parameter name "msgInvalidDrive", looking up the code that used it is at line 2574 to 2579

```
  { Check if it's a valid drive, reconnecting it first if necessary }
  RootPath := RemoveBackslashUnlessRoot(AddBackslash(PathExtractDrive(T)));
  ReconnectPath(RootPath);
  if not DirExists(RootPath) then begin
    LoggedMsgBox(SetupMessages[msgInvalidDrive], '', mbError, MB_OK, True, IDOK);
    Exit;
  end;
```

So i tried making sure that the folder exists. which did not help.

Any idea suggestion on how to resolve this?

browse looks like this:

[image: inno setup browse]

and the error message persists.

Comment: What is that `{sp}` constant ?

Comment: @TLama updated. sd. system drive.

Comment: Thanks! Now what is more important, when does the message is shown ? When you choose the installation directory ? And if so, how do you choose it ? By the browse for folder dialog or by entering the path to the edit box ? And if the latter, in which format, `\\192.168...\Path` or as mapped drive like e.g. `x:\Path` ?

Comment: @TLama Yes, when choosing the folder. and im not using TCP/IP pipe or named pipe (example\\192.168.0.1\folder or \\computer-pc\folder) rather a Map drive such as f:\folder. the error message shown. i try the same for c:\folder, it passes. all in windows 8. in windows 7 it works without the message.

Comment: After you type the path, try clicking on Browse.  This should force Windows to prompt you for login credentials -- after you have entered them, it should work.  Admin-level programs like an Inno installer by default cannot inherit network permissions from non-admin programs like Explorer.

Answer (score 3):

Try using **PrivilegesRequired=lowest** in the **[setup]** section of your .iss script, this should word if you're not using any admin-required functionnality.